# How to set Data Model value on Custom TableView UILabel in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to set Data Model on UIlabel

I used like this code to change

In ConnectiondidFinishLoading

```
 AuditTextBoxarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for(int i=0;i<idarray.count;i++)
            {
                DataModel *model = [DataModel new];
                model.AuditTextBoxString = @"";
                [AuditTextBoxarray addObject:model];
            }
```

In cellforrowatindexpath

```
 cell.lblAuditTextBox.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];
```

On Button Click

```
   NSString *String=textView1.text;
   DataModel *model = [AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:index];
   model.AuditTextBoxString = String;
```

But I am not able to set value of data model in tableview:

[image]

How can I set Data Model value to uilabel? I am doing something wrong, but what I am not getting.

DataModel.h

```
@interface DataModel : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *strSelected;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *TextViewvalue;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *RateViewValue;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *Popupvalue;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *SurveySelected;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *AuditTextBoxString;
```

DataModule.m

```
#import "DataModel.h"

@implementation DataModel

@end
```

I used DataModule to change Button colour and set it on the table view like this

In ConnectionDidFinishLoading

```
    for (int i =0; i<idarray.count; i++)
    {
        DataModel *model = [DataModel new];
        model.strSelected = @"";
        [arrData addObject:model];

    }
```

Button Click

```
sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
DataModel *model = [arrData objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
model.strSelected = @"P";
```

cellforrowatindexoath

```
 //background color change on button
    DataModel *model = [arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"P"])
    {
        cell.passbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
```

Now I am trying to add text on uilabel frok data model.

Comment: `[AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]` That's returning a `DataModel` object. What you are doing, is more or less the same as doing `NSLog(@"%@", anyDataModelObject)`. You are calling description on it. But, I guess, that what you want to show is `DataModel *data = [AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; cell.lblAuditTextBox.text = model.AuditTextBoxString;`?

Comment: @Larme Yes I need to show Data Model data.

Comment: cell.lblAuditTextBox.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ].AuditTextBoxString]; @Muju write this your problem solve

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya It is showing error "AuditTextBoxString"  not found on object of type 'id'.

Comment: @Muju send me demo i will check it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just change code from

```
cell.lblAuditTextBox.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];
```

To

```
DataModel *model = [AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.lblAuditTextBox.text=model.AuditTextBoxString
```

Answer (score 0):

After you update the dataModel in ConnectiondidFinishLoading or On Button Click, Reload the tableview on main thread(if you are in a separate thread) to refresh the data on the View.
something like

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableview reloadData];
});
```

Comment: Can you attach the full code of that View con. actually, it's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: add Logs in cellforrowatindexpath and Check 1.Is it running every time you update your model? 2. Is logs shows the new value fetched from the model?

Comment: You mean the color change of the button background is working but your text changing on the label is not working?

Comment: @Muju what was the outcome from your debug are you able to fix it?