# searching the rest api response result using the swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I have started the programming in swift and trying to implement small search functionality.

I trying to implement search box for searching the different aircraft. For each character entered in search box, result should be refreshed.
I already have a API to get list of aircraft types. sample response type from the API.

```
[
   {
      "type": "jet",
      "seating": "single-seat",
      "engine": "Two-engine",
      "name": "Lockheed Martin F-35 Lightning II",
      "nativeName": "Lockheed"
   },
   {
      "type": "turbojet",
      "seating": "double-seat",
      "engine": "Two-engine",
      "name": "Heinkel He 178",
      "nativeName": "Heinkel"
   }
]
```

How do i search the aircraft using swift and **result to be showed in the tableview** and for each character entered in search box, result should be refreshed.

I'm using below link for reference but sample code would help a lot.
https://medium.com/@nimjea/json-parsing-in-swift-2498099b78f

Thanks

Comment: You need this -> https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-ios-tutorial

Comment: @dahiya_boy - i don't want to search in the tableview, I want to display the result in the tableview after getting response from API

Comment: @Manisha - you need to send ur search character to API and then parse the API response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Data Model value on Custom TableView UILabel in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385407/how-to-set-data-model-value-on-custom-tableview-uilabel-in-objective-c)

Comment: @dahiya_boy - it is about not searching in the tableview

Comment: @Manisha Its all about call Api and show data into tableView which is more simpler.

Answer (score 1):

To get refreshed result from API, You have to check after received Response from API. Please refer below sample code for refreshed result.

```
if textToAPI != self.searchTextField.text{
     self.aryResult.removeAll()
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}else{
    // Add new record into Array received from API         
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```